# Chooser with camera intent and image picker intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, samsung-touchwiz

I have created a chooser for either picking an image from file or for making a picture.

The code I use works fine on a Nexus 5, however when I try it on a Samsung S5, the chooser does not display the camera icons.

```
public Intent makePhotoIntent(String title, Context ctx, String uniqueImageId){

        //Build galleryIntent
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

        //Create chooser
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,title);

        if (checkexCameraHardware()){
            Intent  cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            mTempImage = null;
            try {
                mTempImage = createImageFile(uniqueImageId);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (mTempImage != null){
                cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mTempImage)); //add file ure (photo is saved here)
                Intent[] extraIntents = {cameraIntent};
                chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
            }
        }
        return chooser;
    }
```

[image: Samsung][image: Nexus]

When I change the order in which the intents are added to the chooser the Samsung device does show the camera but only shows android-system as the file option.

```
public Intent makePhotoIntent(String title, Context ctx, String uniqueImageId){

        //Build galleryIntent
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

        //Create chooser
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,title);

        if (checkexCameraHardware()){
            Intent  cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            mTempImage = null;
            try {
                mTempImage = createImageFile(uniqueImageId);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (mTempImage != null){
                cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mTempImage)); //add file ure (photo is saved here)

                //I have to re-create the chooser here or the Samsung will not show the 'camera' icons.
                //I have to add the cameraIntent first.
                chooser = Intent.createChooser(cameraIntent,title);
                Intent[] extraIntents = {galleryIntent};

                //Intent[] extraIntents = {cameraIntent};
                chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
            }
        }
        return chooser;
    }
```

[image: Samsung] [image: Nexus]

Ideally I would like the Samsung device to show the same as the Nexus one when I add the gallery intent first. I can however not get this to work.

Comment: which samsung device you use

Answer (score 8):

- If there are multiple intent matches for the extra intent (`Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`) , it will show all of them combined under **"Android System"**. When you click on "Android System", it will open another chooser with all those intent matches.
- So, in your first screenshot for samsung device, the camera is indeed showing up - its just under "Android Systeem" (clicking this will show all camera intent matches).
- If you make `galleryIntent` the extra instead of camera intent, it will combine all gallery related intents under "Android Systeem" (as seen in your 2nd screenshot for samsung device)

I guess the user can be confused if he does not know what this "Android Systeem" is !

- With below solution you can directly add each one to your `chooser`

  In your 2nd code snippet, replace

  ```
  Intent[] extraIntents = {galleryIntent};
  chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
  ```

  with :

  ```
  List<Intent> galleryIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
  PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
  for (ResolveInfo ri: pm.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)) {
      Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
      galleryIntents.add(intent); 
  }
  chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, galleryIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
  ```

This will manually add each matching intent directly to your `chooser`

Comment: This works, however the activity launched by the picker does not have the action Intent.ACTION_PICK and therfore does not return with the image. If I however add this intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK) the result is always cancelled.

Comment: @Arno you can [`setAction` and other parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String)) on the intent before adding to `galleryIntents` array, please see my update to answer

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem**

Please follow these steps and this is the best and simple way to pick image from gallery and from camera,

Step 1. declare globally variables

```
public static final int rcCC = 33;
boolean isCC = false;
```

Step 2 . Copy these methods and paste your code

```
void picPhoto() {
    String str[] = new String[] { "Camera", "Gallery" };
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setItems(str,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    performImgPicAction(which);
                }
            }).show();
}

void performImgPicAction(int which) {
    Intent in;
    if (which == 1) {
        in = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    } else {
        in = new Intent();
        in.setAction(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(in, "Select profile picture"), which);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        try {
            if (rcCC == requestCode) {
                getActivity();
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    isCC = true;

                }
            } else {
                getActivity();
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    option.inDither = false;
                    option.inPurgeable = true;
                    option.inInputShareable = true;
                    option.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];
                    option.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                        Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
                        uImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Common.getPath(
                                selectedImageURI, getActivity()), option);
                    } else {

                        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;
                        try {
                            pfd = context
                                    .getContentResolver()
                                    .openFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
                            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = pfd
                                    .getFileDescriptor();

                            uImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
                                    fileDescriptor, null, option);
                            pfd.close();

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        ivProfile_image.setImageBitmap(uImage);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Step 3. call the method, where you want to pick pic and show dialog

```
  picPhoto();
```

Step 4.

Make user permission in manifest file,

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I know it can be done by using your own alert dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way, i hope its works for you, i check in samsung galaxy tab 2 it show camera option

Declare your intent like this

```
  Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

    //Create chooser
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,title);

        Intent  cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(uniqueImageId);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); //add file ure (photo is saved here)
            Intent[] extraIntents = {cameraIntent};
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);

            startActivityForResult(chooser, Constants.SEND_IMAGE_FROM_CEMERA);
```

and  getOutputMediaFileUri(uniqueImageId) method this return you Uri of image

```
getOutputMediaFileUri(String uniqueImageId){

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }


        File mediaFile;
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + uniqueImageId + ".jpg");

        return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
}
```

Comment: This is the same as my original example. I know how to create the Uri for the camera intent. This is not the issue.