# Take Image from Camera and Gallery Dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-gallery

I want to make image chooser for Android to take an image from camera or gallery. I found sample code by creating a custom dialog, but  want to make something like this:

[Image chooser dialog in Splitwise](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38871046/media-20150302.png)

How to make dialog like that? Can it compatible with API 10?

*Note: Sorry I can't post images (not enough reputation), so I put a Dropbox link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chooser with camera intent and image picker intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377171/chooser-with-camera-intent-and-image-picker-intent)

Comment: I got some problem with that link, finally I found the correct one from another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12347567/3427434

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing between camera and gallery for image selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218504/choosing-between-camera-and-gallery-for-image-selection)

Comment: Too many similar questions. [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218504/choosing-between-camera-and-gallery-for-image-selection/32475805), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165302/dialog-to-pick-image-from-gallery-or-from-camera), [link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image), [link4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377171/chooser-with-camera-intent-and-image-picker-intent)