# Android 6.0 = PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED (Issue with CONTACTS and LOCATION permission)

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an issue with Android 6.0 = PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED

**P.S.** I FOUND THAT PROBLEM IS WITH CONTACTS AND LOCATION PERMISSION, is anyone know how to fix it?

I can get DATA from JSON , BUT I can't send information to database because of PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED exception.

```
public class DVLAresult extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

    private ProgressDialog progress;
    GPSTracker gps;

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String insertUrl = "http://zonec.net/project/insertDetails.php";

    double latitudeD;
    double longitudeD;

    String postCode;
    private DVLAInformation dvlaInfo = null;

    //DVLA Plate Number
    String dvlaPlateNumber;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dvlaresult);

        //Intent dvla from Index class
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        dvlaPlateNumber = intent.getStringExtra("dvlaNumber");

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my_contacts, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        Intent intentURL = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        //Set URL for similar car, based on retrieved information from current car
        String URL = ("http://www.autotrader.co.uk/search/used/cars/" + dvlaInfo.getMake() + "/postcode/" + postCode + "/radius/5/sort/default/onesearchad/used%2Cnearlynew%2Cnew/page/1/searchcontext/default/colour/" + dvlaInfo.getColour().toLowerCase() + "/fuel-type/" + dvlaInfo.getFuelType().toLowerCase() + "");
        intentURL.setData(Uri.parse(URL));

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            //Panel button which redirect to website with similar car which yser currently was looking for.
            case R.id.action_check_similar:
                startActivity(intentURL);
                return true;

            //Panel button, redirect to report about this application or any other issue
            case R.id.action_report:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Report.class));
                return true;

            //Panel button, redirect to subscribe web-page
            case R.id.action_subscribe:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Subscribe.class));
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void sendGetRequest(View v) {
        //EXECUTE JSON
        new GetClass(this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "DVLAresult Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.sandro.openalprsample/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "DVLAresult Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.sandro.openalprsample/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }


    private class GetClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, DVLAInformation> {

        private final Context context;

        public GetClass(Context c) {
            this.context = c;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
            progress.setMessage(getString(R.string.LoadMethod));
            progress.show();
        }

        //[START] Get DVLA information from website database by using url.
        @Override
        protected DVLAInformation doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                //URL from which information was retrieved.
                final URL url = new URL("https://dvlasearch.appspot.com/DvlaSearch?licencePlate=" + dvlaPlateNumber + "&apikey=d47OE2WB4nqgPQN6");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //Set connection
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseOutput.append(line);
                }
                br.close();

                //Read and parse JSON and responce to string
                DVLAInformation obj = new DVLAInformation(url.toString());
                obj.readAndParseJSON(responseOutput.toString());

                return obj;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }
        //[END] Get DVLA information from website database by using url.




        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final DVLAInformation obj) {
            dvlaInfo = obj;

            final TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showOutput);
            outputView.setText(obj.toString());
            progress.dismiss();

            //[START] Get DVLA information from JSON
            final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(obj.getUrl());
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            output.append("\n").append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            output.append("Make : ").append(obj.getMake());
            output.append("\nModel : ").append(obj.getModel());
            output.append("\nSix Month Rate  : ").append(obj.getSixMonthRate());
            output.append("\nTwelve Month Rate : ").append(obj.getTwelveMonthRate());
            output.append("\nDate of First Registration : ").append(obj.getDateofFirstRegistrationegistration());
            output.append("\nYear of Manufacture : ").append(obj.getYearOfManufacture());
            output.append("\nCylinder Capacity : ").append(obj.getCylinderCapacity());
            output.append("\nCO2 Emmissions : ").append(obj.getCo2Emissions());
            output.append("\nVIN number : ").append(obj.getVin());
            output.append("\nTransmission type : ").append(obj.getTransmission());
            output.append("\nFuel Type : ").append(obj.getFuelType());
            output.append("\nTax Status : ").append(obj.getTaxStatus());
            output.append("\nColour : ").append(obj.getColour());
            output.append("\nType Approval : ").append(obj.getTypeApproval());
            output.append("\nWheel Plan : ").append(obj.getWheelPlan());
            output.append("\nRevenue Weight : ").append(obj.getRevenueWeight());
            output.append("\nTax Details : ").append(obj.getTaxDetails());
            output.append("\nMOT Details : ").append(obj.getMotDetails());
            output.append("\nTaxed : ").append(obj.getTaxed());
            output.append("\nMOT : ").append(obj.getMot());
            //[END] Get DVLA information from JSON


            //[START] Get GPS Location.
            gps = new GPSTracker(DVLAresult.this);

            latitudeD = gps.getLatitude();
            longitudeD = gps.getLongitude();

            gps.stopUsingGPS();

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> address = null;

            try {
                address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitudeD, longitudeD, 1);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            assert address != null;
            if (address.size() > 0) {
                postCode = address.get(0).getPostalCode();
            }
            //[END] Get GPS Location


            //[START] SEND values to database
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                // [START] SEND values to database
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    //Get values from Index activity
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    //Radio button choice
                    String radioChoice = intent.getStringExtra("radioChosen");

                    //Recognition confidence of the plate
                    String confidence = intent.getStringExtra("confidenceResult");
                    //Unchanged recognised plate number
                    String plateNumberUn = intent.getStringExtra("plateNumberResult");


                    //Google user details (ID, Name, Email)
                    Intent intentG = getIntent();
                    String userIdG = intentG.getStringExtra("userIdGresult");
                    String userNameG = intentG.getStringExtra("userNameGresult");
                    String userEmailG = intentG.getStringExtra("userEmailGresult");


                    //Values which will be used to insert to database
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();

                    parameters.put("userIdG", userIdG);
                    parameters.put("userNameG", userNameG);
                    parameters.put("userEmailG", userEmailG);

                    parameters.put("latitude", String.valueOf(latitudeD));
                    parameters.put("longitude", String.valueOf(longitudeD));
                    parameters.put("postCode", postCode);

                    parameters.put("doWithCar", radioChoice);
                    parameters.put("plateNumber", dvlaPlateNumber);
                    parameters.put("confidencePlate", confidence);
                    parameters.put("plateNumberUn", plateNumberUn);

                    parameters.put("make", dvlaInfo.getMake());
                    parameters.put("model", dvlaInfo.getModel());

                    parameters.put("twelveMonthRate", dvlaInfo.getTwelveMonthRate());
                    parameters.put("yearOfManufacture", dvlaInfo.getYearOfManufacture());
                    parameters.put("cylinderCapacity", dvlaInfo.getCylinderCapacity());
                    parameters.put("dateofFirstRegistration", dvlaInfo.getDateofFirstRegistrationegistration());
                    parameters.put("co2Emissions", dvlaInfo.getCo2Emissions());
                    parameters.put("fuelType", dvlaInfo.getFuelType());
                    parameters.put("colour", dvlaInfo.getColour());
                    parameters.put("mot", dvlaInfo.getMot());
                    parameters.put("motDetails", dvlaInfo.getMotDetails());
                    parameters.put("vin", dvlaInfo.getVin());
                    parameters.put("transmission", dvlaInfo.getTransmission());

                    parameters.put("sixMonthRate", dvlaInfo.getSixMonthRate());
                    parameters.put("taxStatus", dvlaInfo.getTaxStatus());
                    parameters.put("wheelPlan", dvlaInfo.getWheelPlan());
                    parameters.put("revenueWeight", dvlaInfo.getRevenueWeight());
                    parameters.put("typeApproval", dvlaInfo.getTypeApproval());
                    parameters.put("taxed", dvlaInfo.getTaxed());
                    parameters.put("taxDetails", dvlaInfo.getTaxDetails());

                    return parameters;


                }
            };
            //[END] SEND values to database

            requestQueue.add(request);


            DVLAresult.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    outputView.setText(output);
                    progress.dismiss();
                }
            });


        }
    }
}
```

I thought about an issue with permissions but android not asking for permission while trying sending information to database.

I have internet permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Error looks like this:

```
04-25 03:01:25.611 29073-29808/com.sandro.openalprsample E/Volley: [615] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
                                                                       at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:480)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:466)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:236)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:210)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:106)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

I have tried this one , but it do not work:

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
            //resume tasks needing this permission
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @fog take reference from here to add permission on runtime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973235/android-permission-denial-starting-intent-with-revoked-permission-android-perm/35973323#35973323

Comment: @Saveen Updated ... have a look on the method I have tried

Comment: @Fog this is not exception related to permission but there is some problem with encoding string using volly

Comment: Please recheck your URL that you are passing

Comment: @Saveen It is problem related to permission, because I turn all permission ON and everything works fine

Comment: Please look your exception

Comment: I need to make permission for Contacts and Location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110089/discussion-between-saveen-and-j-fog).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously. Your targetSdkVersion is targeting 23 and you need to use runtime permission for `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
Android 6.0 include runtime permission feature. Some permissions are considered as dangerous permissions and need to request the at run time. `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is one of them.

You can learn which permissions are dangerous and which permissions are normal from here [Normal and Dangerous Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous).

And you can learn how to use Android Runtime Permission from here: [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).