# onActivityResult returns null for image picker

Tags: android, firebase, null, firebase-storage, onactivityresult

I'm using Firebase Storage to upload images from an Android app. So when I click `photoBtn` button, `image_picker` opens, but when I select an image, the URI is still null.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        StorageReference photoRef=mEventPhotoReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                        downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"got the uri",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });

    }


}

//DISPLAY INPUT DIALOG
private void displayInputDialog()
{
    Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("Save To Firebase");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.input_dialog);

    nameEditTxt= (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    grpTxt= (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.propellantEditText);
    descTxt= (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.descEditText);
    Button saveBtn= (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
    Button photoBtn=(Button)d.findViewById(R.id.photoBtn);
    linkTxt = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.linkEditText);



    photoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);

        }
    });


    //SAVE
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //GET DATA
            String name=nameEditTxt.getText().toString();
            String propellant=grpTxt.getText().toString();
            String desc=descTxt.getText().toString();
            String link=linkTxt.getText().toString();
            Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
            String ts = tsLong.toString();


            //SET DATA
            Spacecraft s=new Spacecraft();

            if(downloadUrl==null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Photo is necessary to add an Event",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                s.setName(name);
                s.setPropellant(propellant);
                s.setDescription(desc);
                s.setLink(link);
                s.setImageUrl(downloadUrl.toString());
                s.setTimestamp(ts);
            }
            //SIMPLE VALIDATION
            if(name != null && name.length()>0)
            {
                //THEN SAVE
                if(helper.save(s))
                {
                    //IF SAVED CLEAR EDITXT
                    nameEditTxt.setText("");
                    grpTxt.setText("");
                    descTxt.setText("");
                    linkTxt.setText("");
                    downloadUrl=null;



                    adapter=new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,helper.retrieve());
                    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name Must Not Be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    d.show();
}
```

Can someone please help me why `onSuccess` method is never executed and `downloadUrl` is always null?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider implementing an onFailureListener to see why it's failing. If on success isn't being called it's because it's not successful. That's where the failure listener comes in.

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);

// Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
    }
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Comment: I found the answer , it was actually the rules that were stopping the image from being uploaded, u changed the rules and everything works fine now

Comment: Ok but you would have been able to find this from checking the failure exception. How did you find the answer?

Comment: Strangely there was something wrong with android studio it wasn't displaying firebase exception log in log messages , i restarted android studio and then it displayed the exception message

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464652/select-image-from-galery-and-show-in-imageview/42464758#42464758) . I'm providing a simple wrapper to get images and receive them correctly

Comment: I just realised that my intent returns data but in onActivityResult the addOnSuccessListener isn't executed , can you tell me what might be the problem

Comment: if you checked my answer you would of seen that you have to change `requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER` to `(requestCode & 0xffff) == RC_PHOTO_PICKER` to get the correct hex value.

Comment: unfortunately it's not working , the line photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener  still doesn't executes

Comment: does it actually reach that part ? try to put a Log there and see if it actually get inside of your if statement

Comment: I must be kicking myself my code was working fine the reason it was not executing onSuccess method was i forgot to make my firebase rules public , anyways thanks for your help issue is resolved