# Android how to request permission based on user action in chooser intent

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-intent-chooser

I'm having a trouble to request user permission based on what they've selected in chooser intent. For now, my program is request the permissions before the chooser intent show up. How can I achieve in a way that request the permissions after they've selected intent. The code below is request camera permission or storage permission first then only allow users to select they want to take picture from camera or gallery.

```
Dexter.checkPermissions(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {

                Intent chooserIntent = null;
                List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

                Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {

                    List<PermissionGrantedResponse> list_GrantedPermission;

                    list_GrantedPermission = report.getGrantedPermissionResponses();

                    //check permission granted
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()){
                        intentList = addIntentsToList(mContext, intentList, takePhotoIntent);
                        intentList = addIntentsToList(mContext, intentList, pickIntent);

                    }

                    else if (list_GrantedPermission.size() > 0){
                        String grantedpermissionName = list_GrantedPermission.get(0).getPermissionName();

                        if (grantedpermissionName.equals(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
                            intentList = addIntentsToList(mContext, intentList, takePhotoIntent);

                        else
                            intentList = addIntentsToList(mContext, intentList, pickIntent);
                    }
                    else {

                    }

                    //request a source
                    if (intentList.size() > 0) {
                        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1),
                                getString(R.string.message_select_source));
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

                        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PICTURE);
                    }

                    if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()){
                        final AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

                        alertBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.message_permission_required));
                        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);

                        alertBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.message_permission_required));
                        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }

            }, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't need the camera or storage permission to use those intents.

Comment: @jing Do you have solution of this question?

Comment: @NitinPatel Unfortunately, I don't have the solution. Do you have the solution ?

Comment: @jing If you are still looking for solution, you can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825525/7806873

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973235/android-permission-denial-starting-intent-with-revoked-permission-android-perm/35973323#35973323) answer about permissions to take or pick pictures.

Also, [ImagePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464652/select-image-from-galery-and-show-in-imageview/42464758#42464758) is an easy way to pick or take a picture.