# RealPath from Gallery image

Tags: java, android, path, uri, android-gallery

I Use classes from this answer

[Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42464758/7575308)

and I have problem implementing code which returned me real path from selected image, I need real route for get FILE on other method (for send to server)

But I'm not successful.

I was trying for hours find something on the web but unsuccessful too.

Please do you have some idea?

(I need send image for server so I need `File image1 = new File(PathString)` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solve this code...

here is good everything

[solution](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/)

Answer (score 0):

> I need real route for get FILE on other method

Step #1: Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content represented by the `Uri` that you received.

Step #2: Create a `FileOutputStream` on some temporary file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`).

Step #3: Copy the content from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`, using standard Java I/O.

Step #4: Use the file that you just created.

Step #5: When you are done with that file, delete it.

Comment: i bet you must be answering that kind of "how to get the real path from my uri" question 10 times a month ;-)