# Camera file chooser not opening in WebView android

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, webview

When uploading, a custom intent pops out containing file icon and camera icon.. File icon is for file upload and camera icon is for image upload after capturing it from camera.. File upload is working fine..But Camera action not working..When I clicked the camera icon it does nothing..I aslo checked the logcat if there are any errors occured..I didn't see any errors..

```
public class QuestionUploaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String Sub_Question_url;


public static final int REQUEST_CODE_LOLIPOP = 1;
private final static int RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM = 2;
private WebView webView;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question_uploader);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    Sub_Question_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("Sub_Question_url");

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    setUpWebViewDefaults(webView);
    webView.loadUrl(Sub_Question_url);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        private String TAG;
        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                    RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM);

        }
        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM);
        }
        //For Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                    RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM);

        }
        //For Android5.0+
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE_LOLIPOP);

            return true;
        }
    });
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setUpWebViewDefaults(WebView webView) {
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    // Enable Javascript
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    // Use WideViewport and Zoom out if there is no viewport defined
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    // Enable pinch to zoom without the zoom buttons
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Hide the zoom controls for HONEYCOMB+
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    }
    // Enable remote debugging via chrome://inspect
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
    // We set the WebViewClient to ensure links are consumed by the WebView rather
    // than passed to a browser if it can
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM:
            Uri uri = null;
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(uri);
            mUploadMessage = null;
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_LOLIPOP:
            Uri[] results = null;
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null|| data.getDataString() == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem and i just remove chooser to directly launch the camera intent and then i've got a crash with an error that said :

```
Android: Permission Denial: starting Intent with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

On this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973235/android-permission-denial-starting-intent-with-revoked-permission-android-perm) they said that we should remove the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

And then it works ! And you can use chooser. Hope it's not too late for you.

EDIT: If you want to use this permission for another need, you just need to ask to the user the permission before launch the chooser. Intent doesn't trigger ask for permission itself.